# Adding validation list to dynamic cell range via VBA in Excel 2013

Tags: excel, vba

I'm just beginning to get into Excel VBA coding, having basic VB knowledge and searching for the appropriate solutions on the net ;)
I'm working on  a staff rostering solution in Excel. It is growing quite complex for a newbie, but I've got time and I am eager to learn.

On my main worksheet, the number of columns equals the number of days for the current month and the number of rows is created by a vba function that loads a list of all clients from another worksheet, so far, so good.

Now i want to populate the validation lists of each cell in this range (firstDayfirstClient:lastDaylastClient) with the list of employee IDs from yet another worksheet. To do so, I managed to write the following function:

```
Sub createDD()
Dim bSh As Worksheet
Set bSh = Sheets("sht_MA")
Sheets("sht_Main").Activate
Dim c As Range
c = Range(Cells(4, 4), Cells(Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, _
    Cells(3, 256).End(xlToLeft).Column))
With c.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
     Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:=bSh.Range("tbl_MA[ID]")
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
End With
End Sub
```

This  always throws me an error 91 (with block variable not set), even if I hardcode the Range with

```
c = Range("D4", "AH6")
```

Can anyone tell me if I am missing something or haven't got the concept right? I have also tried to not use the active worksheet when defining the range but to address it explicitly like so

```
Dim aSh, bSh As Worksheet
Set bSh = Sheets("sht_MA")
Set aSh = Sheets("sht_Main")
Dim c As Range
c = aSh.Range(aSh.Cells(4, 4), aSh.Cells(aSh.Cells(aSh.Rows.Count, 1) _ 
    .End(xlUp).Row, aSh.Cells(3, 256).End(xlToLeft).Column))
```

which is more confusing but doesn't help either.

I hope this gets across what I am trying to say, as I am neither a native speaker of English nor VBA ;)
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Chris

Comment: You need to use the `Set` keyword for objects, as in `Set c = `...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you already did Dim c As Range, that means right now c is a Range Object. Every time you wanna assign value/something to an object, remember to start with keyword SET!

In this case, you should go like this:

```
Set c = Range("D4", "AH6")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is correct, but for readability I encourage you to use capitalization and real words. (If it matters, I'd also upvote it then).

Comment: I am sort of informal guy, but i have done some edit and think it looks better now. @DougGlancy

Comment: Great, thank you very much, that seems to have worked!